# node 8.11 impossible install express and socket.io and uglifier?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, socket.io, npm-install

I try install my project in prod:

```
$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "socket-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "real time server",
  "main": "package",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "uglify": "^0.1.5"
  }
}
```

with cmd : `sudo npm install` but there is error :

```
$sudo npm audit


                       === npm audit security report ===                        

# Run  npm install socket.io@2.1.1  to resolve 9 vulnerabilities
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > debug                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > engine.io > debug                                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > socket.io-adapter > debug                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > socket.io-client > debug                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > debug      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > socket.io-adapter > socket.io-parser > debug     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > socket.io-client > socket.io-parser > debug      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ debug                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > socket.io-parser > debug                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ parsejson                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ socket.io                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ socket.io > socket.io-client > engine.io-client > parsejson  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/528                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > findup-sync > glob > minimatch              │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/118                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > glob > minimatch                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/118                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > minimatch                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/118                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > findup-sync > lodash                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > grunt-legacy-log > grunt-legacy-log-utils > │
│               │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > grunt-legacy-log > lodash                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > grunt-legacy-util > lodash                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt > lodash                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ uglify-js                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.6.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ uglify                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ uglify > grunt-contrib-uglify > uglify-js                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/48                        │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 18 vulnerabilities (14 low, 4 high) in 291 scanned packages
  9 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
  9 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

I try like it said :

```
$ sudo npm audit fix --force

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN socket-server@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ socket.io@2.1.1
added 2 packages from 2 contributors, removed 16 packages and updated 18 packages in 2.228s
fixed 9 of 18 vulnerabilities in 291 scanned packages
  9 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
  1 package update for 9 vulns involved breaking changes
  (installed due to `--force` option)
```

So how can I do?

```
$ npm -v 
6.4.1
$ node -v
v8.11.3
```